# How to find the root of a dependency tree using parent and child information of a node

Tags: algorithm, tree, dependencies, root, nodes

I will first provide some background info. This is how my data is stored:

```
%POM_family{$GAV} = [\%Parents, \%Children]
```

Before posing my question I will define the above variables the way i use them in my context:

- $GAV     --> can be considered to be a random node in our dependency tree
- %Parents --> a hash which contains the list of nodes that $GAV depends on
- %Children--> a hash which contains the list of nodes that depend on our $GAV

My question is the following:

- given that we have the parents and children of any chosen node, what algorithm would be appropriate to use in order to analyze from dependency to dependency and find the root $GAV ie the $GAV who has no Parents.

Thanks in advance! :-D

NOTE: if the question is not clear enough, provide some feedback and I will change my question :-)

Comment: How about keep checking if parent is present, if yes, go to parent, else current is root.

Comment: i would prefer an algorithm that would be more efficient then supposedly visiting all the tree nodes one by one.

Comment: This doesn't visit all the nodes. You start with a node and you traverse to the root via one path (visits log n nodes)

Comment: yup yup i thought about it afterwards. thanks :)